# If x is list, why does x += "ha" work, while x = x + "ha" throws an exception?

Tags: python, list, operators

From what little I know, + op for lists only requires the 2nd operand to be iterable, which "ha" clearly is.

In code:

```
>>> x = []
>>> x += "ha"
>>> x
['h', 'a']
>>> x = x + "ha"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Comment: I "agree" with your question; it this is a good argument against operator overloading for me.

Comment: Deleted my answer after your edit - it seems you're wondering about the rationale behind not supporting + between a list and an iterable - my mistake.

Other than to say, "Yeah, why not?", I don't have an answer.

Comment: that's a *major* breakage.  more generally, any language or library that defines different behaviors for same-looking operators should be considered user-hostile.  no one sane would use `+` for string concatenation: that operation is not commutative!

Comment: @just: OMG!  Python is broken and unusable!  Someone call the media!

Comment: Enough with the hyperbole - it's not the end of the world, but it will definitely cause people to bang their heads, especially when the problem comes up so rarely. I especially like the accepted answer because it gives another surprising dimension to the problem.

Comment: Python : the language that pleases everyone, even Python-haters :) It is imperfect, after all. And it's not math. Neither Perl. So what?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Using `+=` with a list is like calling `extend`, not `+`.

- You can call `extend` with an iterable.
- You can only use `+` with another list.

I can only guess why this decision was made, but I imagine it is for performance reasons. Calling `+` results in a new object being created and all items being copied, whereas `extend` can use free space in the existing list object saving a copy in some cases.

Another side-effect of this decision is that if you write `x += y` other references to the list will see the change but if you use `x = x + y` then they will not. This is demonstrated below:

```
>>> x = ['a','b']
>>> y = ['c', d']
>>> z = x
>>> x += y
>>> z
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

>>> x = ['a','b']
>>> y = ['c', d']
>>> z = x
>>> x = x + y
>>> z
['a', 'b']
```

**References**

[Python source code for list](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/listobject.c?view=markup).

Source code for `+=`:

```
static PyObject *
list_inplace_concat(PyListObject *self, PyObject *other)
{
    PyObject *result;

    result = listextend(self, other);
    if (result == NULL)
        return result;
    Py_DECREF(result);
    Py_INCREF(self);
    return (PyObject *)self;
}
```

Source code for `+`:

```
static PyObject *
list_concat(PyListObject *a, PyObject *bb)
{
    Py_ssize_t size;
    Py_ssize_t i;
    PyObject **src, **dest;
    PyListObject *np;
    if (!PyList_Check(bb)) {
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                  "can only concatenate list (not \"%.200s\") to list",
                  bb->ob_type->tp_name);
        return NULL;
    }

    // etc ...
```

Comment: I think the real question here is, "why such inconsistency?"

Comment: i'm on the verge of going -1 on this answer as it doesn't answer the question at all (see @doublep's comment).

Comment: I don't think it's clear at all that this question is a critique of the design. The first step has to be to understand how the inconsistency is implemented, and this is all we can help with here. The larger questions that you commenters ask are completely outside of the scope of SO, if you ask me :)

Comment: Wow, what a great answer. Meanwhile, I did a search through the PDF I'm reading and it actually says + is concat while += is extend(). The only problem is it says that ~300 pages after the introduction of the + op! And I must admit it was a real shock, seeing as everything else was very intuitive (till now anyway). Thanks!

Comment: @doublep: Practicality beats purity.

Comment: @doublep Throughout Python, the `+=` operator tries to modify mutable objects in place, but creates a new object in the case of immutable objects. This creates a trap for people unfamiliar with this rule that could have been avoided by making `i += j` simply be a shorthand for `i = i + j`, which is the most obvious way to interpret the `+=` operator if you don't know better. In exchange, we gain succinctness: when dealing with mutable objects you can use the `+=` operator for object mutation and the `+` one creating a new object, rather than one of these requiring an explicit method call.

Answer (score 7):

You're thinking about it backwards.  You're asking why `x = x + 'ha'` throws an exception, given that `x += 'ha'` works.  Really, the question is why `x += 'ha'` works at all.

Everyone agrees (I hope) that `'abc' + 'ha'` and `[1, 2, 3] + ['h', 'a']` should work.  And in these cases, overloading `+=` to do in-place modification seems reasonable.

The language designers decided that `[1, 2, 3] + 'ha'` shouldn't, because you're mixing different types.  And that seems reasonable as well.

So the question is why they decided to *allow* mixing different types in the case of `x += 'ha'`.  In this case, I imagine there are a couple reasons:

- It's a convenient shorthand
- It's obvious what happens (you append each of the items in the iterable to `x`)

In general, Python tries to let you do what you want, but where there's ambiguity, it tends to force you to be explicit.

Comment: another tentative -1: to me it's obvious that `x += y` is defined as `x = x + y` for any `x` and `y`.  it's immediately clear that you have avoided answering the question. ;)

Comment: I think the point here is that it is *not* obvious, hence the question. In most other programming languages where both `+=` and `+` is defined, doing `x += y` is usually defined to be the exact same as `x = x + y`. In fact, typically one is an alias for the other.

Comment: It's obvious in the sense that, if you try it, it's very clear what happens.  And it's not as if, if you weren't expecting it to work, you'll be disappointed when it does.

Comment: It is IMHO clear that generally if x=x+y would yield a desired effect, x+=y should also.  The converse, however, is not true.  An object might be constructed so that if two threads simultaneously execute "x+=y;" and "x+=z;" the result will be the same as if the statements executed in some order, but if they execute "x=x+y;" and "x=x+z;" there's no practical way to offer such a guarantee.

Comment: the previous comment ("tentative -1") from me addresses rev.1.  rev.2 is interesting and wouldn't deserve -1 at all, also @supercat's comment is  insightful.

Comment: "just somebody" is making me seriously wish for the ability to downvote comments.

Answer (score 5):

When defining operators, there are two different "add" operators: One is called `__add__`, the other `__iadd__`. The latter one is for in-place additions with `+=`, the other one is the regular `+` operator. http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html has more infos on that.